# Why can I not achieve a smooth surface when subdividing?

Tags: modeling

I'm not sure whether I have created the polygons correctly but I can't seem to get a smooth surface when subdividing. Prior to this I also reduced the complexity of the mesh by reducing the number of polygons, but less polygons made it even worse when subdividing. I've also deleted doubles, converted to tris to quads but with no real success. Can anyone help? thanks

[image]

[image]

Here I have redone the topology but I still get uneven surfaces. I'm also trying to convert the odd tri's into quads but I can't seem to do this without having to rebuild the topology?
[image]

Comment: The first step is having clean topology consisting of quads only. Triangle faces will cause the issues you're seeing.

Comment: The only way is to redo the topology. If you don't want to do it manually perhaps Instant-Meshes can be of help (https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes).

Comment: Thanks guys! I have re-done the topology - please see last image above ^ . I get better results but i still do not achieve a circular smooth edge when subdividing. There aren't many triangles left but I'm not sure how to get rid of them without having to redo the topology. (I've tried to the tri to quads already)

Comment: This is a simplified example how the topology should look like to get good results with subdivision https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBqOe.jpg

Comment: Are you starting from a sphere?

Comment: Your re-topo isn't clean enough.For subdivision to get a good result, you need a proper edge flow, which basically means evenly distributed quads along the edge, with opposite sides connecting each other. So that new edges added by subdivision modifier can form a continuous, closed ring. That's why it's better to avoid boolean operations if you decide to use subdivisions later, since boolean almost always messes up your topology. For how to properly cut a hole on a subdivided surface: https://topologyguides.com/post/124120926080/adding-holes-to-a-flat-surface

Comment: aha! great, thanks a lot! I'm a blender noob but this all makes much more sense now

Comment: @barkest I'm usually a CAD monkey so yes I did start from a sphere. I then used the knife tool to cut out the edges, separate the surfaces, off-set it, and created new faces to build the chamfers. I then deleted some faces to create a more quad-like topology....but from what i've gathered this is not the correct way in building quality smooth surfaces....

Answer (score 3):

I took a default sphere with 32 segments

[image]

Into edit mode and select a single vertex. When selected then bevel it <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

[image]

with the faces still selected <kbd>right click</kbd> and select loop tools. If you do not have them then they are in the add ons (google how to use add ons from preferences). Select circle

[image]

this will give you a nice circle shape to work from.

[image]

Add knife cuts as shown or alternatively select the two verticies you want to join and press <kbd>j</kbd>

[image]

Select the circle edges and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to offset the edge loop you have selected. This will give you 2 new edge loops.

[image]

Select the inner faces and extrude inwards three times using the normal orientation

[image]

You will end up with this topology

[image]

Add a subdivision surface modifier x 2 and set the auto smooth to 60

[image]

You can put it into a circular array and tweak the depth/scale of the hole

[image]

Comment: this is tremendous! thank you!